# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
if (Trim(document.getElementById("txtAffiliateName").value)=""){
       alert("Please enter 'Affiliate Name'.");
       document.getElementById("txtAffiliateName").focus();
       return false;
}
```

When I use this code in ASP.NET it give the alert :

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result

With `continue,ignore,break` options,when I click on `continue` it goes to page load and working properly and when I click on  `break` it stops the execution.

```
if (document.getElementById("txtAffiliateName").value="") {
       alert("Please enter 'Affiliate Name'.");
       document.getElementById("txtAffiliateName").focus();
       return false;
}
```

When I remove the `Trim` the alert error message is not showing. But the `TextBox` value will be empty on button click.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: `=` is assignment `==` is comparison.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) to know why is it better to use === than ==

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Comparison Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) `==`.

Change this:

```
if (Trim(document.getElementById("txtAffiliateName").value) = "")
```

To this:

```
if (Trim(document.getElementById("txtAffiliateName").value) == "")
```

Comment: Thanks For the help, i didn't notice that